# Cloud Foundry - How to subscribe/watch firehose events?

Tags: events, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud, cloud-foundry

**Task**: To write a simple standalone app(`app1`) that can subscribe(watch)  firehose events from pivotal cloud foundry. Yet to understand the technology to be used for `app1`.

Python is my primary skill, but open for Java or GO, if required

`app1` need to subscribe(watch) for `Staging complete` events of any app running across Orgs in Pivotal Cloud Foundry and receive the app details and then trigger `cf env <app_name>` to get environment details of the app that just got into staging.

---

Any app is pushed with a manifest file, having environment variables(as shown below)

```
    --- applications: 

     - name: some-app

        instances: 1 

        memory: 1G 

        buildpack: java_buildpack_offline         

        path: target/artifact.jar

        routes: - 
              route: some.router.com 

         services: 
              - abc

               - def

           env: 

                 ARTIFACT_VERSION: 0.0.1
```

---

1) which technology is more suitable(supported) to perform this task? to basically watch Firehose events and run `cf env <on_that_app>`

2) Is my code(`app1`) suppose to be running within PCFoundry to watch Firehose events? Can I run `app1` outside PCF to watch Firehose events?

Please share some resources on learning about firehose events in PCFoundry(PAAS), as novice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang concept (please don't expect any copy/paste codes):

1. get log messages from Doppler - 
   use [cloudfoundry/noaa](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/noaa) and watch only for log `Staging complete`
2. call CF client and get env variable value - use [cloudfoundry-community/go-cfclient](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/go-cfclient)

You can watch Firehose events from anywhere. You just need network connectivity to Doppler URL, so development can be done on `localhost` dev machine and production version can be running in Cloud Foundry. You can use websockets, so you can push changes directly to the browser. IMHO final Golang implementation will need `disk_quota: 64M` and `memory: 16M`.